# Constant variable in C

Tags: c

I'm running a simple code to test my understanding, as of below.
The output that I got from this is actually 10.
I thought that the output should gave me a compile error, as "b" couldn't be add to x, as x is a const variable.
Can someone help to clear my understanding on this?

```
int aFunction(const int x){
    return (x+10);
}
int main(){
    int b =0;
    b = aFunction(b);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x + 10` does not change `x`, it makes a new value out of the inputs `x` and `10` .   `x += 10` would change `x` (and give an error)

Comment: "b couldn't be add to x"? You're not adding b to x.

Comment: You do not modify x in your `aFunction` function, you just use it an addition parameter. `x + 10;` do not change the value of `x`. When you invoque `aFunction`, the compiler make a copy of `b` that it pass to the function.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
   return (x+10);
```

Doesn't add 10 to `x` and return it. It forms the value that is `x+10` and returns that but leaves `x` itself unchanged.

If you wrote

```
 int c;
 c=x+10;
```

Would you expect x to be increased by 10 after that second line executes?

Try

```
int aFunction(const int x){
    int c=(x+10);
    printf("aFunction: x=%d c=%d\n",x,c);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, applying the const qualifier to a variable prevents the value of the variable from being modified.
In your function, aFunction(), the variable x is given a const qualifier which prevents the value of x from being modified in your function. There is no reason why your code shouldn't be able to compile since all the function is doing is returning a value which is 10 more than x. It is not in any way modifying the value of x.

If you did something like x += 10 which is short for x = x + 10, then you will get some compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

`const int x` only means that `x` itself cannot be changed inside the function. It has nothing to do with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

***Simple:*** 
x is not changed until or unless you re-initialize it, look into these lines :

**const int x** : means X will never be changed.

**x+10** : means just add 10 in X but never save the status.

**x = x +10 "** means overwrite the value of x which will Crash: and you will get desired Error